# question related to Goldbach Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I was wondering if there is a proof to the following statement. 
Every even number $n \gt 30$ can be expressed as a sum of a **odd** prime and a relatively prime **odd** composite number (being relatively prime to $n$).

Examples: 26 = 15 + 11, 48 = 23 + 25; 50 = 23 + 27 etc. 
Thanks!

Comment: `a sum of a prime and a composite number` You may want to change that to `an *odd* prime` to eliminate the obvious. Then, how about the even number $6\,$?

Comment: $1$ is not prime or composite. On the other hand, the first even number that hold the statement is $5+9=14$, but $18$ doesn't hold it.

Comment: You are right. I was counting 1 as composite. If not, this statement is likely true for $n > 30$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For even $n$, let $p$ be a prime occuring in the interval $[\frac{n}{2},n-2]$, and let $q=n-p$. Then $n=p+q$, and since $q<p$ and $p$ is prime, the summands will be relatively prime odd integers. The existance of at least one $p$ is guaranteed for $n>6$ by the Strong [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate). This construction may fail to give a composite $q$ for some $p$ in the interval.

If, for every prime $p$, we still obtain a prime $q$, then we have made as many partitions of $n$ into two primes as there are primes in $[\frac{n}{2},n-2]$. Let the number of these Goldbach Partitions be given by $g(n)$. This would imply then that $g(n) = \pi(n-2) - \pi(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$. A [result](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper91.pdf) on the upper bound of Goldbach Partitions (Theorem $(1)$ in the paper), shows that the last $n$ for which $g(n) = \pi(n-2) - \pi(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$ is $210$, and for all following $n$, $g(n)$ is less than this number. Therefore, there must exist at least one composite $q$ for all $n>210$.

For $n\le210$, it may be computationally checked to see if they have such a partition, the prime would have to occur, in these cases, in $3\le p < \frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: This is a nice argument, but you missed the OP's condition that $q$ must be composite.